# What does "Break outside Loop" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner!

I am trying to make a program that reads in X whole numbers and outputs (1) the sum of all positive numbers, (2) the sum of all negative numbers, and (3) the sum of all positive and negative numbers. The user can enter the X numbers in any different order every time, and can repeat the program if desired.

In order to add the repeat function I have added "break" to the loop. However when I try to run it it shows an error that says "break outside loop". I am unsure what this error means and how I can go about fixing it.

```
while True:
    many = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter:"))
    Sum = 0
    sumNeg = 0
    for i in range(0,many,1):
        num = float(input("Please enter number" +str(i+1)+":"))
        Sum = Sum + num
        if num < 0:
            sumNeg = sumNeg + num
    print('Sum =',Sum)
    print('sumNeg =', sumNeg)
repeat =input("Would you like to repeat? (Y/N):")
if repeat != 'Y':
    break
```

Comment: `break` tries to break a loop, but your `break` statement is not inside a loop. Your last if should be indented.

Comment: The line with `repeat =input("Would you like to repeat? (Y/N):")` and the following lines are not part of the loop. Check the indentation of those lines.

Comment: Two off topic points to note: 1) don't start a variable name with a capital letter. 2) sum = sum + num should be in an else statement if you want sum of all positive numbers.

Comment: thank you, this helped a lot ... I will keep the capitalization error in mind as well

Answer (score 0):

The break statement is outside the loop because it's parent if statement is outside the loop.

```
while True:
    many = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter:"))
    Sum = 0
    sumNeg = 0
    for i in range(0,many,1):
        num = float(input("Please enter number" +str(i+1)+":"))
        Sum = Sum + num
        if num < 0:
            sumNeg = sumNeg + num
    print('Sum =',Sum)
    print('sumNeg =', sumNeg)
    repeat =input("Would you like to repeat? (Y/N):")
    if repeat != 'Y':
        break
```

Comment: Please don't answer blatant typo/indentation questions with full answers, since answers interfere with automatic deletion processes once the question is closed.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I will keep that in mind in the future, should I delete the answer then?

Comment: Eventually I suggest that you do, thanks for  understanding. You can wait until the question is closed: your answer might stop further answers from being posted :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Will do, thanks for the advisement!

Comment: Thank you J Clark. This helped a lot, my program is running now, I guess you are free to delete the comment now, I apologize!

Comment: @sameera your question is perfectly fine, no need to apologize:) It's just unlikely to help future readers by its nature.

Comment: I understand, I will keep that in mind when I ask questions in the future, thank you :)